# Windows Service The underlying provider failed on Open Problem

Tags: c#, windows-services, entity-framework-4

I Developed Windows Service with EF4.0.

There is a some standart code in my code that is run in console application.

```
private void ServiceTimer_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

  this.timer.Stop();

  try
  {

    using (PHEntities pe = new PHEntities ())
    {           
      var result = (from c in pe.tblCustomer
                    from j in c.tblJPConfig
                    select new { c.ID, c.ExpireTime, j.printed}

                             );
      foreach (var item in result)
      {
         .....
      }
   }

   this.timer.Start();

}  
catch (Exception ex) 
{
  eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);              
}
```

After this code run, Event viewer write "The underlying provider failed on Open Problem" Error.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

That means that it is having trouble connecting to your database. Check your connection string and passwords. Check that the database accepts incoming connections. Try connecting manually (using SQL Server Management Studio if it is an MS SQL Server)

Comment: When i try to this windows service application on my laptop and test database there is no problem. But When i install this windows service application on live server. I'm getting this error. Also when i put this timer my windows applicaton ther is not any problem.

Comment: Check that the connectionstring you use when the service is installed on the live server is correct (in particular, check that it doesn't point to the test database on your laptop). Verify that you can connect to the live database manually with the credentials provided in the connection string.